# Configuring 3proxy Socks5 behind NAT network - error 12

Tags: proxy, centos, nat

I'm trying to configure 3proxy server using [this guide](https://pastebin.com/fwv3JfUD) (I've already used it on OHV hosting and it works just nice!), now trying to start 3proxy behind NAT, and have error [12 of 3proxy](https://3proxy.ru/howtoe.asp?l=RU#ERRORS) which means *12 - failed to bind()*
Where is mistake and what I'm doing wrong?

```
Internal IP:
172.16.20.50 
External IP:
82.118.227.155
NAT Ports:
5001-5020
```

Here are my entire config:

```
######################
##3Proxy.cfg Content##
######################

##Main##

#Starting 3proxy as a service/daemon
daemon

#DNS Servers to resolve domains and for the local DNS cache
#that providers faster resolution for cached entries
nserver 8.8.8.8
nserver 1.1.1.1
nscache 65536

#Authentication
#CL = Clear Text, CR = Encrypted Passswords (MD5)
#Add MD5 users with MD5 passwords with "" (see below)
#users "user:CR:$1$lFDGlder$pLRb4cU2D7GAT58YQvY49."
users 3proxy:CL:hidden

#Logging
log /var/log/3proxy/3proxy.log D
logformat "- +_L%t.%. %N.%p %E %U %C:%c %R:%r %O %I %h %T"
#logformat "-""+_L%C - %U [%d/%o/%Y:%H:%M:%S %z] ""%T"" %E %I"
rotate 30

#Auth type
#auth strong = username & password
auth strong

#Binding address
external 82.118.227.155
internal 172.16.20.50

#SOCKS5
auth strong
flush
allow 3proxy
maxconn 1000
socks -p5011
```

User 3proxy created, access to 3proxy granted.

Logs, which means connection established, but no traffic transfered (0/0):

```
[root@bgvpn113 ~]# tail -f /var/log/3proxy/3proxy.log.2018.05.14
1526329023.448 SOCK5.5011 00012 3proxy MY_LOCAL_IP:21151 88.212.201.205:443 0 0 0 CONNECT_88.212.201.205:443
1526329023.458 SOCK5.5011 00012 3proxy MY_LOCAL_IP:21154 88.212.201.205:443 0 0 0 CONNECT_88.212.201.205:443
1526329023.698 SOCK5.5011 00012 3proxy MY_LOCAL_IP:21158 88.212.201.205:443 0 0 0 CONNECT_88.212.201.205:443
1526329037.419 SOCK5.5011 00012 3proxy MY_LOCAL_IP:21162 195.201.201.32:443 0 0 0 CONNECT_195.201.201.32:443
1526329037.669 SOCK5.5011 00012 3proxy MY_LOCAL_IP:21164 195.201.201.32:443 0 0 0 CONNECT_195.201.201.32:443
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mistake was in outside IP.
I set both ips to 172.16.20.50 and it started to work!